# Finding exact node C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I was trying to implement drag and drop in treeview .
I generate the root nodes first then if I drag any item over the treeview I want to put it under **exact root nodes**.
I need something like

```
private void treeView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
TreeNode tNode = FindNodeAtPoint(e.X, e.Y); 
}
```

so that from tNode I can find it's root node and can populate it under that parent node.

can anybody help me out with findNodeAtPoint() functionality.

```
private TreeNode FindNodeAtPoint(int x, int y)
        {            
            Point p = new Point(x, y);
            p = PointToClient(p);
            ................
            ................
            ................
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at this link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307968

I think it's what you need. especially the part of `GetNodeAt` method.

Answer (score 3):

```
private TreeNode FindNodeAtPoint(int x, int y)
{            
      Point pt = treeView1.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
      return treeView1.GetNodeAt(pt);
}
```

Hope this helps